# How to get value of Qualtrics Drag & Drop Choice using Javascript

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I have what should be a simple answer. I have a drag and drop style multiple choice question on Qualtrics. I have recoded the answers as I wish. I think it assigns to each answer a variable like QID15_1 QID15_2 QID15_3, etc. The outputted data then gives the rank order of that selected option.

So if I ranked them, for example

1. QID15_3
2. QID15_1
3. QID15_2

The value of QID15_3 =1, the value of QID15_1=2, and the value of QID15_2=3.

What is the correct syntax to access these values? I want to set an Embedded Data item with the value of QID15_1, for example (so it should equal 2), but I can't seem to get it correct.

I've tried Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getSelectedAnswerValue and things like this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: With the help of a friend who knows Java, we figured it out. You can write something like

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnUnload(function()
{var order=document.getElementById( 'QR~QID15~1' ).getElementsByClassName( 'rank' )[0].innerText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set an embedded variable in JavaScript. You can just pipe the value wherever you need it (in a subsequent question, in the survey flow, etc.). It would be:

```
${q://QIDx/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/y}
```

where x is the question id and y is the choice id.

EDIT:
You can assign it to an embedded data variable in the survey flow like this:

```
edvar = ${q://QIDx/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/y}
```

Comment: I'm running an experiment, so what I'm trying to do is calculate things for each question (especially payments, since one is randomly selected). And it would be nice to have the data in the format I want using embedded data. But I can fiddle around with this and see if I can get it to do what I want. I actually tried this earlier and didn't think it worked, but that's because I had been using the recoded value as the choice id. So if anyone sees this in the future, use the original choice id and not a recoded value. Thanks for the help!